# array declaration

Tags: php, mysql

I want an array to be declared like `$value=array('apple'=>'red', 'mango'=>'yellow').`
now i want this values to be fetched from the database.
both the apple and the red.
suppose this coloures are saved in table called 'colors' and fruits in the table 'fruits', with the color_id.
now how to fetch them and put inside this array.

i tried to put the codes in side the bracket like array(code to fetch) but it did'nt work.
anybody can help?

table->fruit(fruit_id, color_id, fruit_name)
table-> color(color_id, color_name)

```
 $result=mysql_query("select * from
 fruit_table");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     $row_color-mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select color_name from colors where
 color_id=$row['color_id']"));
 $val[]="$row['fruit_name']=>$row_color[color_name]";

 } 
$data=implode(",",$val);
 $value=array($data);
```

thanxx in advance.

Comment: mysql, wamp server phpmyadmin

Comment: Post what you have tried. Plus, which DB are you using?

Comment: What's the exact table structure? Please post the table create statements for the "colors" and "fruits" tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you will have to do.

1. Perform a query to get the required information from the database.
2. Turn the result from the query into the format you want.

Here's some example code (assuming you have already made a successful connection to the database).

Assumptions I've made on your database schema are:

- You use `id` as the primary key in both tables
- `name` is the field that contains the color/fruit names

If they are correct it should work, otherwise minor adjustments are required to the query

```
$result = mysql_query('
    SELECT fruits.name as fruit, colors.name as color 
    FROM fruits 
    JOIN colors 
    ON fruits.color_id = color.id');

if (!$result) {
    die(mysql_error());
}

$value = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $value[$row['fruit']] = $row['color'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: thanxx a lot!! it worked.. i always find my answers here.. :)

Answer (score 1):

This way?

```
$value = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($mySqlQuery)){
    $value[$r['fruit_field']] = $r['color_field'];
}
```

MySQL query isnt here; hope you already have it.

Comment: thanxx a lot!! got my solution!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to make the following work.
This is basically the concept of the key value pairs in the ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY

```
//Assuming the name of the fruits column is fruit_name and color column is color_name

$value = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM colors as c LEFT JOIN fruits as f ON c.color_id=f.color_id";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$fruitname = $row['fruit_name'];
$colorname = $row['color_name'];
$value['$fruitname'] = $color_name;
}
}
```

At the end of the loop the value array will have the values as required.

Thanks
J

Comment: Using `LEFT JOIN` will result in rows that have a color, but no fruit.

Comment: thanxx a lot!! got my solution!!